# How to setup one virtual host configuration for multiple subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Is it possible to setup one virtual host configuration for multiple subdomains using some sort of pattern matching?

What I want to achieve is something like the following:

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
  ServerName www.([a-z]+).domain.tld
  DocumentRoot /www/subdomains/$1
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache/$1_error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache/$1_access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `ServerName` does not support regexp. `ServerAlias` only supports wildcards (e.g `*.domain.tld`). It could be that your best bet would be to use `mod_rewrite`...

Comment: Thanks. looking into it: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html

Comment: Also, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html